# Next.js 13 pattern for changeable API fetch request

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a seemingly simple Next.js app directory pattern where I want the ability for a user to cycle through pages of data fetched from the server. Take a simple example below, where I want the user-changeable state of `currentPage` to be passed to my article fetch request. What is the best practice for this pattern? The current setup below will cause an infinite loop issue because `listArticles` needs to be called in a server component, but then I cannot pass a dynamic page value to the fetch request. How do I pass this page to the fetch request?

**page.tsx**

```
// Parent
export default async function Page() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
    return (
        <>
            <h3>Articles</h3>
            <ArticleList
                currentPage={currentPage}
            />

            <button onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}>Previous page</button>
            <p>Current page: {currentPage}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}>Next page</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

**ArticleList.tsx**

```
// Child server component
export default async function ArticleList({
    page = 0,
}: {
    page?: number;
}) {
    const listArticles = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? SITE.URLS.TEST : SITE.URLS.LIVE}/api/articles?&page=${page}`, {
            method: "GET",
            next: { revalidate: 5 },
        });
        
        if (!res.ok) {
            console.error("Error fetching articles:");
            console.error(res);
        } else {
            return res.json();
        }
    }
    
    let data = await listArticles();

    return (
        <>
            { 
                data.articles.map((article: any) => (
                    <div key={article.id}>
                        {article.id}
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would go about this is by persisting the current page inside the query and then using the `<Link />` component to redirect the user to the correct url. This allows you to completely renounce client components for this specific use case.

---

###### Very simple implementation example

As you see I use [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) in when parsing the current page, this ensures that the `currentPage` variable is always `1` if no page was provided.

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default async function Page(props) {
  const params = props.searchParams;
  const currentPage = parseInt(params.get("page") ?? "0", 10);
  return (
    <>
      {/* Rest of your JSX */}

      <ArticleList currentPage={currentPage} />

      <Link href={{ pathname: "/articles", query: { page: currentPage - 1 } }}>
        <button>Previous page</button>
      </Link>

      <Link href={{ pathname: "/articles", query: { page: currentPage + 1 } }}>
        <button>Next page</button>
      </Link>

      {/* Rest of your JSX */}
    </>
  );
}
```

---

Also I see an error in the initial code snippet you have provided, you can not use hooks (like `useState`) inside a server component.

Comment: This seems to be a fully functional solution for this! Thank you!!